# Should I Join all the tables to prepare an object data or call separate SP for separate property in the object?

Tags: c#, database, object, sqlconnection

```
public abstract class Asset: IAsset
    {

        **Some Other Properties**

        [ForeignKey("AssetTypeId")]
        public AssetType AssetType { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UploadedById")]
        public AppUser UploadedBy { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UpdatedById")]
        public AppUser UpdatedBy { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ApprovingUserId")]
        public AppUser ApprovingUser { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("AssetConditionId")]
        public AssetCondition AssetCondition { get; set; }

        public AssetCheck LastAssetCheck { get; set; }

        public AssetAllocation AssetAllocation { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a class having multiple properties that contain a large count of properties. These properties represent separate tables in the database. So when I fetch the data from the database, I have two options.

a) First approach is to join all these Tables and marking alias names to columns of these tables and prepare the object data on the Data Layer.

b) Since I already have a separate Data Layer for each entity. I can call these methods to fetch data for each entity separately. But in this case, it will increase the number of calls/connections to the databases.

So which approach is better?

Comment: Which programming language is that?

Comment: c# asp.net @a_horse_with_no_name